# Python pickle doesn't print out characters such as 'â,é,č,ć'

Tags: python, utf-8, pickle

I am not very familiar with programing jargon, so bear with me.

I'm making a language program that has to be able to save and read from a file text that contains utf-8 characters.

I'm using pickle

```
WORDS = [['eat','manger','v'],['drink','boire','v'],
["cake",'le gateau','n'],['coffee','le café','n']]

wordDatabase = open('wordsForProgram.txt','wb')
pickle.dump(WORDS,wordDatabase)
wordDatabase.close()

inFile = open('wordsForProgram.txt','rb')
newList = pickle.load(inFile)
print(newList)
```

It prints out:

```
[['eat', 'manger', 'v'],
['drink', 'boire', 'v'],
['cake', 'le gateau', 'n'],
['coffee', 'le cafĂ©', 'n']]
```

The list in the script also changes 'le café' to 'le cafĂ©'. When I change it back it works again until I close and reopen the script.

Thanks!

Comment: As i can see from the sample noting happens to the WORDS variable. Are you trying to print newList?

Comment: What happens when you print `WORDS` *before* you dump to the file? You have UTF-8 encoded data but your terminal might not be configured for UTF-8 *display*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top of your file?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle
WORDS = [['eat','manger','v'],['drink','boire','v'],
["cake",'le gateau','n'],['coffee','le café','n']]

wordDatabase = open('wordsForProgram.txt','wb')
pickle.dump(WORDS,wordDatabase)
wordDatabase.close()

inFile = open('wordsForProgram.txt','rb')
newList = pickle.load(inFile)

for i in newList:
    for j in i:
        print j
```

The output is the same for WORDS and newList:

```
eat
manger
v
drink
boire
v
cake
le gateau
n
coffee
le café
n
```

Also you can try with codecs module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle
import codecs
WORDS = [['eat','manger','v'],['drink','boire','v'],
["cake",'le gateau','n'],['coffee','le café','n']]

wordDatabase = codecs.open('wordsForProgram.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
pickle.dump(WORDS,wordDatabase)
wordDatabase.close()

inFile = codecs.open('wordsForProgram.txt','rb')
newList = pickle.load(inFile)

for i in newList:
    for j in i:
        print j
```

Comment: Hm, it seems to work now. Even if I just print the inFile it doesn't change it to cafĂ© anymore. Did the -for i in newList- do something or was it just the "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-". If so, isn't commented code supposed to be unreadable?     Oh, and thanks! Whatever you did seems to have worked. :)

Comment: It is not commented it is a encoding declaration http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pylang/Encodingdeclarations.html

Comment: codecs doesn't seem to be necessary at the moment. If something gets spoiled I'll try that too.

Comment: As @Martijn Pieters said it might happen that the terminal doesn't support the encoding.